# Flatten and concatenate array keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to flatten and concatenate some nested arrays in PHP, whatever the dimension of the array, and return a single level array of all the concatenated data.

Given array:

```
[
   'dashboards' => [
      'statistics' => [
         'tab_names' => [
            'spare',
            'robot',
          ]
       ]
    ]
];
```

Desired output:

```
[
   'dashboards_statistics_tab_names_spare',
   'dashboards_statistics_tab_names_robot',
];
```

However, I tried to adapt some code found here, came up with that:

```
function flattenArray($array, $prefix = '') {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $newKey = $prefix . $key;
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, flattenArray($value, $newKey . '_'));
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            $result[] = $newKey . '_' . $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The output is almost OK, but I'm having some unwated characters in the strings:

```
[
   'dashboards_statistics_tab_names_0_spare',
   'dashboards_statistics_tab_names_1_robot',
];
```

How can I get rid of the numeric keys ?

Comment: Maybe `$newKey = $prefix . (!is_numeric($key) ? $key : '') ;`?

Comment: @jijihbt Are you certain that 'spare' or 'robot' (or any other value) will not appear more than once in the most inner array? If so, you need to keep the numeric index (in some form), or you will lose entries.

Answer (score 0):

I just made some changes in your code, if the `$key` may be a `numeric` when no index is given.

I also use `rtrim` to avoid extra _ at the end of the string when it's the last value of an array.

```
function flattenArray($array, $prefix = '')
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_numeric($key)) {
            $newKey = $prefix . $key;
        } else {
            $newKey = $prefix;
        }

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, flattenArray($value, $newKey . '_'));
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            $result[] = rtrim($newKey, '_') . '_' . $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving the suggestion of @user3783243 a solution can be this:

```
function flattenArray($array, $prefix = '') {
    
    $result = [];
    
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        
         // $newKey = $prefix . $key;
         
        $newKey = $prefix . (!is_numeric($key) ? $key : '') ;
        
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, flattenArray($value, $newKey . '_'));
            
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            
            $result[] = $newKey . $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The prefix is not updated if the key is numeric (last array level) and also the underscore is not added for values of type string

Answer (score 0):

I think to get rid of the numeric keys, the code for checking for numeric keys should be added to the codebase.

I attached my code snippet:

```
function getFlattenArray($array, $prefix = '') {
    $arr = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $newKey = $prefix . $key;
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $arr = array_merge($arr, flattenArray($value, $newKey . '_'));
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            if (!is_numeric($key)) {
                $arr[] = $newKey . '_' . $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```